# Connecting to Oracle Database in SQL Developer shows only my pluggable databases and NOT the template - PDB$SEED

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, pluggable

all,

First question of mine and I cannot find the answer anywhere for ~6 hours now so if it has already been asked/answered, I am sorry.

I am following this [guide](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-create-and-configure-pluggable-database-12cr1#dbca-create-pdb) even though it is for 12c and I am using Oracle Express Edition 21c currently.

I have created my pluggable databases, configured my listener.ora/tnsnames.ora files AND connected to the database both via sqlplus and via Oracle SQL Developer and I cannot seem to find the PDB$SEED template in the "Container Database" folder in DBA navigation menu as seen on the attached SS:
[NOPDB$SEED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Corm.png)

My pdbs in sqlplus look like this:
[PDBS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZGlM.png)

Other information that might be useful is [listener.ora file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28y9T.png) and [tnsnames.ora file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN28u.png). I am using Oracle Server 8.4 as well.

EDIT: [SELECT name, open_mode FROM  v$pdbs ORDER BY name;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoPmt.png)

Thank you for the help beforehand and if there is anything more that I should provide, I will.

Comment: what do you want to do with the PDB$SEED exactly ?

Comment: That guide is from 2016. I think shortly after that, the SQL Developer team removed `PDB$SEED` from the DBA view, since it is a read-only system container.

Comment: we don't show it b/c there's nothing really you can do with it

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to see PDB$SEED use the V$-Views (e.g. V$DATAFILE). But as Roberto Hernandez already noted: what do you you want from that thing besides look at it?
You are not allowed to change anything in it, not even take it readwrite - and if you finally achive to get rid of it, congratulations, you have damaged your database :-)

Comment: I wanted to see it so I can view the characteristics and try to change it's mode, try to edit it, but if you're saying that I'm not allowed to, then I accept your answer.

Thank you.